# Installing external packages in spark on spylon kernel

Tags: apache-spark, jupyter-notebook, scala-spark

I'm looking for a way to install outside packages on spylon kernel. I already tried initialize spark-shell with --package command inside the spylon but it justs creates another instance. I tried %%init_spark and launcher.packages, but it didn't work too. There's anyway to install an external package, from spark-packages for example?

Answer (score 0):

Just need to move the `jar` to the `$SPARK_HOME/jars` folder. I wish that I could download and use it in the Notebook, but this works for now.